# using strophe with openfire and phonegap

Tags: cordova, openfire, strophe

i am using strophe in my app in because i need to transfer messages between two users.
i follow allmost every tutorial on the web in order to implement my app. also define BOSH in the server.
everything works almost fine but the problems start when i use the cellular internet and not wifi. 
the app is disconnecting from the openfire server. i get error message 'invalid SID' 
and then it takes while until it reconnect again.
i try to follow tutorials which explain how to use attaching sessions. i did not found a'lot of details in the subject.
with attaching it still disconnecting from the server.
anyone can help me with good tutorials and explenations that might help me?
thanks in advance for any help